# New to Ruby on Rails, Javascript functionality not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm rather new to Ruby on Rails (and programming in general), and I've been following through a tutorial to try and get the basics down, but I've stumbled across some functionality that the tutorial doesn't seem to properly set up.

What I've been able to figure out is that apparently JavaScript-related functionality in general is just not working (my symptoms so far are that a bootstrap-triggered dropdown doesn't appear and the `link-to` method just ignores any `method:` code passed to it and only sends a `GET` request), but I'm not sure what I need to do to get this stuff to work - I've tried everything I can find.

What I have done:

- Run `$ yarn add jquery bootstrap`
- Made sure my `application.html.erb` file contains `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`
- Added the following code to `config/webpack/environment.js`:

  ```
    const webpack = require('webpack')
    environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
      })
    )
  ```
- Set up my `assets/javascript/packs/application.js` file to look like this:

  ```
    // This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
    // present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
    // a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
    // that code so it'll be compiled.
    //
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require jquery-ui
    //= require_tree .

    import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
    import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
    import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
    import "channels"

    import "jquery"
    import "bootstrap"

    Rails.start()
    Turbolinks.start()
    ActiveStorage.start()
  ```

And for the record, the problematic code bits are:

- Failing dropdown code (the dropdown menu simply does not appear on click):

  ```
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenuLink">
          PLACEHOLDER <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Profile', current_user %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
  ```
- Failing `link_to` code (it sends a `GET` request instead of a `DELETE` request):

  ```
    <li><%= link_to 'Log out', logout_path, method: :delete %></li>
  ```

I don't feel like I have the background knowledge to further investigate. What am I missing in all of this? Am I completely off base as to what the problem is?

Comment: If you inspect the page do you see any errors in the console?  Can you see jQuery either being included on the page, or not being included on the page when you inspect it?

Comment: @RockwellRice Ah, I do see an error, `cannot find module @popperjs/core`; which I thought I installed, but apparently I didn't. How do I go about adding that?

Comment: Same way you added the other JS libraries?

Comment: @DaveNewton Well, that seems to have solved my problem! I feel kind of stupid now. I think when I tried to install it earlier I didn't realise the `@` was part of the name, and it must have failed in a way I didn't notice. Thank you!

Comment: `yarn add @popperjs/core`

Comment: @EmilienBaudet Yeah, I think I was doing like `yarn add popperjs/core` or something and getting back weird errors I didn't understand. Thank you!